# While working on my Platformer game in Unity, my Update function as it's assigning "true" to a bool even when character is not Grounded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Firstly, the code:

```cs
    private bool? _hasJumped = false;
   
    private void Update() 
    {
        Debug.Log("Checking the _hasJumped value in Update(): " + _hasJumped);
        Debug.Log("Is the player Grounded?: " + IsGrounded());
        
        if (IsGrounded())
        {
            _extraJumps = _extraJumpCount;          
            _coyoteTimer = _coyoteTimerVal; 
            _hasJumped = false; //The Variable that I am having issues with.
            Debug.Log("This statement only runs when the player is on ground!");
        }
        else
        {
            _coyoteTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }

    public bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(_feetpos.position,_feetCheckRadius,_groundLayerMask);
    }

    public void GetJumpInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        
        if (context.started)
        {
            _jumpBuffer = Time.time;
        }

        if (_coyoteTimer > 0f && (Time.time - _jumpBuffer >= 0) && context.performed)
        {
            if(context.interaction is TapInteraction)
            {
                _myRigidBody.velocity += new Vector2 (0f, _jumpForce);
                _whichInteraction = 0;
            }
            else if (context.interaction is HoldInteraction)
            {
                _myRigidBody.velocity += new Vector2 (0f, _jumpForce);
                _whichInteraction = 1;
            }
            _jumpBuffer = null;
            _hasJumped = true; //_hasJumped set to true when I first jump

            Debug.Log("The Player Has Pressed Jump!: " + _hasJumped);
        }
        else if (_extraJumps > 0 && context.performed && hasJumped) //Double Jump should ONLY work when I have jumped, and not when I fall off a ledge.
        {
            Debug.Log(_hasJumped);
            _extraJumps--;
            if(context.interaction is TapInteraction)
            {
                _myRigidBody.velocity += new Vector2 (0f, _jumpForce*_secondJumpForceMult);
                _whichInteraction = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _coyoteTimer = 0f;
        }
    }
```

Sorry if the the code is confusing, I've tried to add comments to the variable in focus. But the issue that I'm facing is this:

Right now, when a player falls off the edge, the player is able to jump once because of the additional "extra jump" but this should not be happening. The "extra jump" should only come into effect when the player HAS already jumped.

To stop this, I decided to use a bool "_hasJumped" which (in my head works as follows):

1. As long as the player is touching the ground, it is false.
2. When the player first jumps, it is set to true.
3. Only when it is true can player perform the "extra jump".
4. If it isn't true, the player cannot perform the "extra jump".

However, the issue that I'm facing is that although _hasJumped is set to true when I jump, it is immediately set to false in the next update (even though I'm still in the air!). [Video Evidence #1](https://youtu.be/lMykjDZvCP0)

I've checked that my IsGrounded() function is working completely fine [[Video Evidence #2]](https://youtu.be/WicstUwxM80).

The only reason I can deduce is that it may have something to do with Unity's runtime order? I'm a newbie though so I could be wrong.

I am also using the new Input System.

Thank you for taking the time to read it/give advice/help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Have you added the correct video links? they aren't opening in the browser

Comment: And what is “context” and its many properties. How are they set

Comment: @GeekyQuentin The links are working for me. I'm sorry for the issue though, I'll upload them on YT and then add then re-add the links.

Comment: @BugFinder context is essentially an inbuilt unity Struct that is triggered when we press the specified action using the new input system. This is the unity documentation on it which will be of more help: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext.html

Comment: @MoonLearns fair enough. Last time I looked at the new input you assigned it a name of your own not got given one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how fast the update actually runs in relation to the way you structured your code.

To visualize, this is what happens when the player pressed the jump button:

[image: First-Frame]

*First frame: Player presses jump button*

[image: Second-Frame]

*Second frame: Character is slightly up on the air, **but the overlap collision detector is still touching the ground***

---

#### Solution

Only check for `IsGrounded()` when the player presses the jump button, not per-update.

> This also saves some computing resource as doing Physics calculation per-frame can be demanding.

Use [`OnCollisionEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) or [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) to check if the character has just landed to set `canExtraJump` to false.

Looks something like this:

```cs
bool canExtraJump = false;

void Update(){
    // Set extrajump when player inputs jump button, and char is grounded
    if (Player_Input_Jump) {
        if (IsGrounded()){
            Jump();
            canExtraJump = true;
        }
    }
}

void TriggerLandedOnGround(){
    canExtraJump = false;
}

// ...

/// Ideally this function should be in the character's feet (as another gameObject)
/// As you do not want this to trigger when the side of a character touches the platform.
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
    if (other.CompareTag("platform")){
        TriggerLandedOnGround();
    }
}
```